# remove package installed by brew

Tags: homebrew, scala

Package name : sbt

Path : /usr/local/cellar/sbt

what I have try :

`sudo rmdir sbt -i` on my terminal but get 
"`rmdir: sbt: Directory not empty`"

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this one:

> brew uninstall sbt --force